# Git/Mercurial Workflow

Tags: git, mercurial, workflow, branch, clone

we try to establish a Mercurial worflow relying on Vincent Driessen Blog.

My question is what is the best way to make the master branch?

- create a branch (hg branch)
- clone the develop repository to master (hg clone)

We start with the second way but some people think that its harder than a branch...
But i think its the best way to separate the production to the features...

(we come from cvs!)

Thanks.

(sorry in advance for my english!)

Comment: The answer to your question is pretty much down to personal opinion.  I would prefer to keep them all together in one repository using branches because I find them easier to manage than separate repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the best way to make the master branch?

Use [hgflow extension](https://bitbucket.org/yujiewu/hgflow/wiki/Home) (branch-based, not clone-based) and do not re-invent the wheel

Comment: Thanks,
I will migrate my master repository to a branch.
I will try hglow extension after.